# Lookup formula to subtract last input data point

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula that will subtract my current value from my last data point. I run a production report and over the weekends we do not produce any product.  I would like the value typically from a Friday be used for calculating the change in production for Monday.

I have an input page for all the data and then a calculation page for the reports.

(Input page)

```
Thursday    1000
Friday      5000
Saturday    "blank"
Sunday      "blank"
Monday      2000
```

Ideally the output page would look something like this:

(output)

```
Friday      4000
Saturday    "blank"
Sunday      "blank"
Monday     -3000
```

Having the last inputted data (being the 5000 value from Friday) subtracted from the  Monday value of 2000.

Comment: I don't see enough information to work with. Presumably you need more than a formula that subtracts from a specified cell, but what? ... or, do you not know how to create such a formula in Excel? If that's it, I suggest you delete this post and try `Help` in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="S","",Sheet4!B3-INDEX(Sheet4!B:B,MATCH(1E+100,Sheet4!B$1:B2)))
```

with adjustment of cell references to suit.

Comment: I tried this.  I end up getting the right value on a Friday but then get values on saturday, and a blank on monday.  Tuesday thru Thursday work.  If i could i would like to look at the last value on Friday and have Monday subtract it.  Like skipping Sat/Sun.  But this is where it gets tricky,  we sometimes only run 4 days a week so typically then Fridays are left blank also.  Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

My idea was:

```
=IF(B2=0,"Nonproductive",IF(B1<>0,B2-B1,B2-OFFSET(B2,-(COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2,-3,0,3),"nonproductive")+1),0)))
```

Imagine you've got your days in column A, and production in column B.

Copy and paste this from cell C2 onwards.

What this does, is first test if there was any production on a given day, if there was 0 production, or in your above example, "blank", then it will give the value "nonproductive". If there was production on that day, it will test if the day prior had any production, if it did, it will simply deduct yesterdays from today. If the day prior had no production, it will count the number of times that "nonproductive" has occurred in the 3 days prior and add that to the number of days in the past it looks.

On a long weekend, it would count 3 nonproductives, so it would compare Monday to Thursday.

Monday - (1 (default offset for the day prior) + 3 (due to nonproductives)

Monday - 4 = Thursday.

Notes:
This will not work for the first 2 rows because the offset will be trying to find cells that don't exist. Even if

The only problems arise when a break greater than 3 days happens, or you have a day off, then a day on, then a day off, then a day on, such as a Tuesday bank holiday, this is because there are 2 "nonproductive" days in the 3 days prior, but we only want it to increase the offset by 1. This could be avoided through continuing a chain of "if" condition checks, but it doesn't sound as though that is required.

This will work for a 2 or 3 day weekend, and some mid-week holidays